# Software to copy/export directory stucture, folders, sub-folders, files properties,metadata wihtout copying the actual content of files?

Tags: windows

- Softwares like DirLister, Snap2HTML etc
- I have a external disk of size 2tb,, and laptop with 500gb SSD and free time at work..
- Copy Volume Shadow of External Disk, just directory structure and files, files metadata only/not actual content of file.
- Basically I want to copy just directory structure, folders, files properties/not the actual content of file; from external disk to my Laptop SSD
- Copy them to my SSD and then take to work and re-arrange file, folder, change directory structure and then flash the changes i made to my external disk when Im home.
- Important is to copy just directory structure, folders, files properties..
  Its Ok if It cant flash changes made to the directory onto disk.. I can do that manually
- It would be like virtual disk (virtual disk without actual files)..
- Are there any 3rd party software that can do it..
  Any software which copy list of file,folder,directory structure, and display them as if viewing in explorer
- dir /b /s >extractlist.txt this cmd gives text file output with directory structure, file size & date.. And its pain in eye to go through those words.. So I was thinking if there is any software which fakes as windows explorer/any file explorer and shows shadow of external disk.Just cloning directory and file name and its properties.
- Everything software has Export File List (.efu) I want something similar..Export directory structure, and file properties, just timestamp and what size the file was.